# TensorFlow MNIST for Experts low accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I have followed the tutorial of tensorflow MNIST for Experts. And I write the code like below which is a copy of the tutorial. However, when I run my code, the accuracy is only 92%, 86%,... It runs very fast only 1 or 2 mins on my mac. And with the step increases, accuracy

```
step 0, training accuracy 0.08
step 100, training accuracy 0.1
step 200, training accuracy 0.16
step 300, training accuracy 0.22
step 400, training accuracy 0.1
step 500, training accuracy 0.18
step 600, training accuracy 0.26
step 700, training accuracy 0.16
step 800, training accuracy 0.24
...
step 19600, training accuracy 0.9
step 19700, training accuracy 0.82
step 19800, training accuracy 0.98
step 19900, training accuracy 0.86
test accuracy 0.9065
```

But when I run the official code [mnist_deep.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py). It works very slowly and output is

```
step 0, training accuracy 0.1
step 100, training accuracy 0.84
step 200, training accuracy 0.84
step 300, training accuracy 0.9
step 400, training accuracy 0.88
step 500, training accuracy 0.92
step 600, training accuracy 0.98
step 700, training accuracy 0.96
step 800, training accuracy 0.96
step 900, training accuracy 0.96
step 1000, training accuracy 0.96
step 1100, training accuracy 0.94
step 1200, training accuracy 0.96
```

It works well. I compare my code and the mnist_deep.py. Only difference is that they use with. Why does my code work so bad? And why they should use with? Below is my code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

def main(_):
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])
    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(20000):
            batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
            if i % 100 == 0:
                train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
                print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
                train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

        print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main=main)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put your `train_step.run` call inside the `if i % 100 == 0:` block.